# Split Two Dates from One String Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dateformatter

I have a button that when the user presses it, it saves the date of an event to their calendar using a start date and end date for the event.

This start date and end date is loaded from a json response, but both dates are recieved in one string.

The format that I receive for the response is like this:

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "date":"5/12/2021 - 5/14/2021",
      },
      {
         "date":"6/22/2021 - 6/25/2021",
      }
       ]
}
```

In order to save to the calendar properly, I need to separate the start and end date from strings formatted like this: "MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY" so that the first date in the string is a variable called startDate and the second date is a variable called endDate.

I am able to parse the json response and the button works fine if I hardcode two "dummy" arrays, but how do I split the response into two separate date variables once I receive this "MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY"?

Comment: Implement `init(from decoder : Decoder)` and add the logic to split the `String` into two `Date`s

Comment: I am able to parse the json response, but how do I split the date once I receive this "MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY"?

Comment: You can't with a DateFormatter, you have Two dates, so you need to split the string into 2 strings representing 2 dates first, and then on each one use the `DateFormatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    let events: [Event]
}

struct Event: Codable {
    let date: String
    
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        
        let splitted = date.components(separatedBy: " - ")
        
        guard let startDateString = splitted.first,
              let endDateString = splitted.last else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "'date' should follow the format 'DATE1 - DATE2'"))
        }
            
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy"
            
        guard let extractedStartDate = formatter.date(from: startDateString),
              let extractedEndDate = formatter.date(from: endDateString) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The provided dates are not in the correct format M/dd/yyyy"))
        }
        startDate = extractedStartDate
        endDate = extractedEndDate
    }
}
```

And an example parsing it from your json:

```swift
let json = """
{
   "events":[
      {
         "date":"5/12/2021 - 5/14/2021",
      },
      {
         "date":"6/22/2021 - 6/25/2021",
      }
       ]
}
"""

let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(response.events)
```

Comment: I think it would make more sense to make the date properties optional than force unwrapping so many times

Comment: Since the Event would make no sense without the dates and init(decoder) throws, I preferred to make it crash with force unwrapping

Comment: Making them optional would leave it to the calling code to decide what to do when a date is nil, "make it crash" is a _really_ bad habit.

Comment: Better to throw a DecodingError

Comment: Btw your dateFormat is WRONG. It should be `"M/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: Yeah, probably throwing a Decoding error is the best option in case of wrong data. And regarding the date format, I tried both with MM and just M and both seem to be working

Comment: yes DateFormatter is lenient but I wouldn't count on it

Comment: Nice, I am editing it right now, I guess you always learn something

Comment: `.init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Invalid string for date interval:" + date)`

Comment: Btw this will create a new DateFormatter for each event object you are parsing

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leodabus/9fe0f0a05b410af872cccc8ad2c66a88